# Design-Time Errors in the Windows Forms Designer(.NET Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

Why Showing This Error? And is there any solution for this kind of error? first time i am facing this type of problem. please help

[image]

Comment: i was upload screen shot of this problem but it is not showing  here. sorry for this @TaW

Comment: Click on the Go to code link and fix the problem in the Register.Designer.cs file manually

Comment: thank u so much @ZoharPeled now it is working

Comment: Have you deleted the mentioned event handler method?

Comment: Yes, now it is working @taffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case #1: You referenced another component in your own project. You need to compile before opening the designer (the designer uses the last built binary in this case which is not always right).

Case #2: You edited the designer file to contain something that can't compile. You need to fix this before the designer will open.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it is working correctly now @Joshua